# Tapas manga about a guy going into a simulation where he would take care of children

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga from Tapas was about a guy going into a simulation where he would take care and help whatever child he got grow up healthy and well. I thought it was super cute, but then I forgot the name of it. I only remember the little boy's name being Mir and that there was a butler who was like the guidebook for the main protagonist, being the guy playing the simulator (forgot his name). I really wanna pick up where I left off on it, but can't seem to remember the name at all. Please, if someone thinks they know it, I'd like to know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

This is *Childminder* by Peacock Kim but it was removed from Tapas so I don't know where you could read it:

> One day Hyun gets chosen to test out a parenting game called Childminder. He thought the game would be easy because all he had to do was be a good father to a very cute child named Mir. However Hyun eventually finds out Childminder is not a normal game nor is Mir a normal child. — [Korean Webtoons Wiki](https://koreanwebtoons.fandom.com/wiki/Childminder)

Found thanks to a [post on the Tapas forum](https://forums.tapas.io/t/solved-trying-to-find-a-premium-comic-i-once-read-on-tapas/42839).